# Generating a Reporting Services 2005 PDF report and storing it on disk

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, pdf, reporting-services

Is there an easy way to generate a PDF report from an RDL that's been uploaded to Report Manager and put that file somewhere on the server's disk? I already have a location on disk to put the file, I just need to know how to programmatically generate the PDF. This is for SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services. Code in either VB or C# is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This **[article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160928012839/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/bsherwin/archive/2007/04/29/112094.aspx)** will show you how you can generate PDF report from reporting service, without using report viewer. Only change you have to do is to write the result byte array into a file stream instead of sending it to response stream as shown in that example. The above mentioned example is using the web services provided by SQL reporting service to generate report.

Comment: i'm working through this article. if it gets me what i need, i'll mark this as answered. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to do it programatically? Report Manager has this funcationality built in already. You just setup a new subscription for that report. Instead of setting the delivery as Email, change it to Windows File Share. You can also change the report format to PDF within those options.

Comment: yes, it needs to be done programmatically. the code has to block until the report is done.